# IOS/SWIFT How to make the button highlight for a period of time with swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I change the button background color when the button is highlighted with swift，then I also want to know . How can I make this background color last for a period of time instead of clicking it to disappear immediately? For example, I want it to disappear 2 seconds after clicking. I checked some information and couldn't find a way. All I can think of is to write a click event, then change the background color of the button and set a time to change it back

Comment: Try to **completely** define what you want. Change the background color on *touch-down* or *touch-up* (after Tap)? What should happen if touch-down and then drag off the button before touch-up? What should happen if you've changed the background color and the user taps the button again before it changes back?

Comment: Just like the calculator button effect brought by apple, the background color changes when I click it, and slowly recovers after 1 second

Comment: Create a button with `UIView` for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the method. As a novice, I can't fully understand it, but it can be used. Friends with similar problems can refer to it

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
@IBInspectable var normalBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = normalBackgroundColor
    }
}

@IBInspectable var highlightedBackgroundColor: UIColor?

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        if oldValue == false && isHighlighted {
            highlight()
        } else if oldValue == true && !isHighlighted {
            unHighlight()
        }
    }
    
}
func highlight() {
    animateBackground(to: highlightedBackgroundColor, duration: highlightDuration)
}

func unHighlight() {
    animateBackground(to: normalBackgroundColor, duration: highlightDuration)
}
var highlightDuration: TimeInterval = 1

private func animateBackground(to color: UIColor?, duration: TimeInterval) {
    guard let color = color else { return }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: highlightDuration) {
        self.backgroundColor = color
    }
}  }
```

You can create a new file and write the above code
Then bind the button class as shown in the figure

[image]

Finally, your button has the content you want in the right property panel
[image]
You can modify the animation time by changing the value of highlightduration